# MFMailComposeViewController treats html attachment as image on iOS7

Tags: html, ios, email, ios7, attachment

When I'm adding html file to the MFMailComposeViewController instance as an attachment the final email is generated with this attachment as embedded image on iOS7, however it worked fine on previous versions (iOS4, 5, 6).

```
[mailController addAttachmentData: fileData mimeType: @"text/html; Charset=utf-8" fileName:@"file.html"];
```

Final .eml content

```
<div><br><br>
<img src="cid:C7BFF544-754D-4322-A71C-12345667789" id="C7BFF544-754D-4322-A71C-12345667789"></div></body></html>

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8;
name=file.html
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename=file.html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Id: <C7BFF544-754D-4322-A71C-12345667789>
```

When it is opened in gmail this attachment is displayed as 'not found' image.
It looks like native mail client treats this document as an embedded image however it's not.

I've tried to use different content-type combinations (application/pdf, charset-8/16) and it doesn't works. Only changing filename extension to for example '.shtml' resolves this issue. However changing filename is inapplicable for me.

Any thoughts?

Note: this application is built with iOS 6 SDK and XCode 4.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a signature being added to your email, like "*Sent from my iphone*" etc.? 
Remove it and resend the email and attachment and see if the attachment suddenly appears.

There seems to be a problem with Apple Main and Outlook where Outlook will strip out attachments if there is any text added after the attachment has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the later response but shortly after posting I found an answer.  Apple and Exchange have some issues and in order to fix this problem I had to make sure that all of the PDF docs I was adding to the message had more than one page.  Simply removing the signature would work but was not valid solution.  I appreciate the response and I hope this might help you as well. Just make sure the attachment has more then one page and everything will work great.

Comment: What should I do in case if I need to add one-page attachment?